# Является ли связкой слово "значит"?

Tags: грамматика, связка

В Грамоте.ру указано, что слово "значит" не является связкой и только глагол "значить" в форме "значит" может употребляться в значении связки (значит = все равно что), при этом тире не ставится: "Простить значит забыть. Забить ещё гол значило выиграть первенство мира".

Это тоже новая грамматика? Тогда интересна ее история: как слово "значит" считали то связкой, то не связкой.

http://www.dslib.net/russkij-jazyk/stanovlenie-razlichnyh-svjazochnyh-komponentov-v-imennom-predlozhenii-v-svjazi-s.html

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку. Что-то я ничего подобного на Грамота.ру не нахожу.

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E7%ED%E0%F7%E8%F2%FC&all=x
Наберите в Грамоте.ру слово "значить" , а не "значит".